# On the morphism induced by inclusion of fields in Hartshorne II 6.10

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes

[image]

This was a question bothered me since II 4. I would like to ask explicitly how can a inclusion of fields induce a morphism?

Meanwhile, regarding the application of Proposition 6.8, we will need the fact that the image space is the whole space. How can we show that the image of the designated morphism $\varphi$ is the whole space?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: The proof immediately tells you it's a morphism because of I.6.12. Is your question really about how I.6.12 works, or do you understand that result and something else is breaking down?

Comment: On how I 6.12 works and also why the image is the whole space.

Comment: This is described in I, 6.12 right? Given $K_2 \to K_1$ you induce a map $C_{K_1} \to C_{K_2}$. As for applying 6.8 you just need to rule out case (1) of 6.8 that the image is a single point. But this means its a constant function so $f \in k$.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm reading the same corollary and I don't get why $(f)=\phi^*((0)-(\infty))$. If either of you understand this please help me out=)